# Mouse keeps left-clicking and scrolling up on its own in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, xfce

I recently installed Xubuntu 18.04 for the first time, and a few days ago I noticed that my mouse is acting weird.

Every time I'm in the file manager, as well as some menus with tabs, the mouse scrolls up on its own. On some programs, like for example Arduino IDE, the mouse keeps left-clicking continuously on its own. On other programs though, like Firefox, and in my Windows 7 partition, everything works perfect. Though on Firefox there seems to be some sort of trouble as well, but only in certain pages.

This, as you can imagine, makes my Xubuntu partition nearly unusable.

It's NOT a hardware problem, since I tested multiple mice wired AND wireless on multiple USB ports and I tested the mice on other PCs.
Hover click is grayed out so it's not it either.
I tried resetting mouse options to default and changing the Double click time, it did nothing.
I tried logging in as a new user, the problem persists.
Disconnecting my Wacom tablet made no difference.

I asked in #xubuntu IRC, received a few suggestions, didn't help. I made a post at r/Xubuntu and opened a topic on Launchpad and on the Ubuntu forums, same result.

My mouse is Bluetooth (though I did try a wired one, as well as different USB ports), my PC is a desktop. I have Xubuntu 18.04 with Compton.

Comment: Does this still happen with no peripherals plugged in at all? Disconnect your mouse, keyboard, Wacom tablet and try again. If it doesn't happen, reconnect one at a time until it starts again. It could be an issue with the keyboard? Perhaps the space key is faulty - that could cause scrolling and clicking.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't help.Disconnecting the Wacom makes no difference, disconnecting the keyboard makes no difference, and disconnecting the mouse and connecting another mouse still does the same thing.

Comment: So with everything disconnected all at the same time, it still happens?

Comment: Yes, I retried it just now to be sure. I disconnected everything except the mouse and the problem still persists. I suspect that if it was hardware it would affect my Windows 7 partition, but everything seems to be working as good as always there.

Comment: Turns out I'm not very bright.

After disconnecting everything again, including the mouse this time, I booted the system, and the mouse still worked. I had completely forgotten that I switched my bluetooth mouse with one that has its own tiny dongle. After I found it I disconnected and reconnected it and now it works fine.

Thank you SO MUCH for the help and sorry for wasting everyone's time with my forgetfulness.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm not very bright.

After disconnecting everything, including the mouse, I booted the system, and the mouse still worked. I had completely forgotten that I switched my bluetooth mouse with one that has its own tiny dongle. After I found it I disconnected and reconnected it and now it works fine.

Thank you all SO MUCH for the help and sorry for wasting everyone's time with my forgetfulness.